# HTML PHP How to add quantity and price value to checkbox and submit

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i am trying to create a restaurant order summary where the customer can select his order via CheckBox and quantity and get the sum of prices at the End.
I just can't seem to figure out how to add the quantity to my code.
It is saying at the end : You have selected Chicken (for example)
I want it to say: You have selected 5 Chicken 
Here it is:

```
<body>
<h3>Select what you want to eat</h3>

<form action="PlaceOrder.php" method="get"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="1"/>Chicken,Price:8
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="2"/>Meat,Price:3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="3"/>Souvlaki,Price:2.50<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="4"/>Pizza,Price:12<br />

<input type="submit" value="Order"/>
</form>
```

and php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["choice"])){
$food=$_GET["choice"];
$quantity=$_GET["quantity"];
$c = count($food);
$price = 0.0;


for ($i=0; $i<$c ; $i++){
    if ($food[$i] == 1){
        $price = $price + 8;
//here it's not working with quantity
        echo "You have selected " .$quantity." Chicken <br>";
    }
    if ($food[$i] == 2){
        $price = $price + 3;
        echo "You have selected Meat <br>";
    }
    if ($food[$i] == 3){
        $price = $price + 2.5;
        echo "You have selected Souvlaki <br>";
    }
    if ($food[$i] == 4){
        $price = $price + 12;
        echo "You have selected Pizza <br>";
    }       
   }

  echo "Total: ".$price . "<br>";
}
else {
echo "Please select something!";
}


?>




</body>
```

[image: My Picture Example please view]

Comment: $quantity[i] could solve. I hope so..

Comment: Don't you need quantity text field with each checkbox?

Comment: You gave me the right direction, thank you, but actually it should be:
    $quantity[$i]

that solved it ! now if i put 2 in the quantity box with chicken checked i am getting you have selected 2 chicken . Works perfectly! tnx

Comment: Yes i do, but started with only the first one just to give it a try to see if it works

Comment: I you want to get the number of quantities of chicken only once in your form you better define your **name** attribute of the quantity field as **quantity**. Dont specify it as array

Comment: can u please give more details on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

No need to give name as array because only one specific value(Only for chicken) you need here,  remove `[]`

```
<input name="quantity" type="text" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />
```

Do:

```
<input name="quantity" type="text"><br>
```

Additionally, you don't need ending `/` (like `<br />`), it doesn't give anything (I have removed these in my suggestion).

And here's a little improved code to show an additional "s" letter if more than 1 has been selected:

```
echo "You have selected ".$quantity." Chicken".($quantity > 1 ? "s" : "")." <br>";
```